# Sym links issue on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

I have a virtual box installed, and a guest OS of Ubuntu 12.04 on it. 
I have installed the guest additions too. So after mounting a shared folder and trying to build from that same mount folder I get this error

> `ln : failed to create symbolic link : Read-only file system`

Any suggestions or solutions ?

Comment: I'm assuming the "read only" checkbox in the shared folder options isn't checked, right? What about the output of `mount`?

Comment: @NathanC Thanks for the quick response. I haven't checked the read only option. The mount output is as follows                                        "Foldername mountpoint type vboxsf (gid=1001 rw)"

Comment: also i have added the user of my guest os to the vboxsf group

Comment: Is the host Windows? I've never actually tried creating symbolic links on a shared folder from linux.

Comment: @NathanC No the host is also a Ubuntu 12.04 machine .